# beanName must not be empty

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm fairly confident there is some class or jar issues going on but I'm not clearly seeing what it is. The beanName error doesn't bring up very useful data on any kind of search. I am trying to launch this on Tomcat 8 when I get the error. I am running on hibernate 5. This is my error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/data.xml]: 'beanName' must not be empty; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'beanName' must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1404)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1394)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'beanName' must not be empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.RuntimeBeanReference.<init>(RuntimeBeanReference.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.RuntimeBeanReference.<init>(RuntimeBeanReference.java:46)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:220)
    ... 18 more
```

Here is the referenced bean in the data.xml:

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="${database.dataSource}" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.adilly.giftlist.model.BaseEntity</value>
                <value>com.adilly.giftlist.model.EmailOptOut</value>
                <value>com.adilly.giftlist.model.Event</value>
                <value>com.adilly.giftlist.model.EventComment</value>
                <value>com.adilly.giftlist.model.EventUser</value>
                <value>com.adilly.giftlist.model.PersistentLogins</value>
                <value>com.adilly.giftlist.model.User</value>
                <value>com.adilly.giftlist.model.WishItem</value>
                <value>com.adilly.giftlist.model.WishItemComment</value>
                <value>com.adilly.giftlist.model.WishItemReservation</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${database.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${database.showSQL}</prop>
<!--
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
-->

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are pointing a property to the datasource!

```
<property name="dataSource" ref="${database.dataSource}" />
```

You should create a bean with the id "datasource" and refence it on your sessionFactory! Take a look at the example:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>         
</bean>
```

Then, on your `sessionFactory`, change to this:

```
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
```

Take a look at [Spring JDCB Documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)

Comment: So in this application, there are several other beans referencing a property like that where it is ${database.SOMEITEM} should I set this bean up to hold all of those values inside it and where they need to point to?

Comment: The problem @falcon12 is that the property dataSource from sessiomFactory doesnt expect a property from a external config,  but a Speing bean! You should create the datasource bean as I explained to you.

Comment: It makes sense. For more context, I inherited this application in its current state so I'm working through what's wrong with it. I'm told the state it is in it is running but I'm skeptical. I'm a .net dev primarily so beans are a little tough to get a handle on for me. I'll work through this and come back and accept the solution if this works, just give me a little time.